# How to apply conditional styling to a cdkDragPlaceholder?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I am trying to change the background color of a custom drag placeholder based on a conditional that checks for certain overlaps. I am logging the value of the boolean and it updates correctly, yet the styling does not get updated. I am using [ngClass] which is not working for me. The base value gets not overwritten.

This is how my code looks:

```
<div
    class="droplist"
    cdkDropList
    cdkDropListSortingDisabled
    [cdkDropListData]="entries"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="entryDropped($event)"
    [cdkDropListSortPredicate]="insertLastSpot"
    (cdkDropListEntered)="checkForOverlapsOnEnter($event)"
    (cdkDropListExited)="hideCustomIndicator()">
    <app-entry *ngFor="let entry of entries"
                         (click)="selectEntry(entry)"
                         [entry]="entry"
                         cdkDrag
                         [cdkDragData]="entry">
      <div
        *cdkDragPlaceholder
        [ngClass]="
        {'example-custom-placeholder-warning': showCustomIndicator,
         'example-custom-placeholder': !showCustomIndicator}">
        <p *ngIf="showCustomIndicator">Overlap!</p>
      </div>
    </app-entry>
  </div>
```

The base value for showCustomIndicator is false. It always shows example-custom-placeholder, even if it is true.

Comment: The template part looks fine. My guess would be change detection (perhaps you're using OnPush strategy? or stuff that happens in the cdkDropList happens outside of ngZone?) but it's hard to say anything until you reproduce the issue on stackblitz.

Comment: Can you show us your example-custom-placeholder /-warning style?

Comment: @Schrader 

```.example-custom-placeholder {
  background: grey;
  height: 45px;
}

.example-custom-placeholder-warning {
  background: red;
  height: 45px;
}```

Comment: @isaac1996 Are you changing your value while dragging and expect the color changes over different items?

Comment: @Schrader I am calculating the value on enter. I guess at this point the placeholder is already generated with the 'old' styling.

Answer (score 1):

How @totallynewb mentioned, there could be an issue with angular change detection while dragging and changing values.

I recreated this and if you run changedetection while dragging, its changing your color

Small example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gjhatj

So you should look into it.

Comment: If I run change detection like you my color does not change, so I guess it could have something to do with the actual value of showCustomPlaceholder. Thanks for the input, I will refactor my code a bit and get back to you

Comment: I refactored the code so showCustomIndicator is a FormControl and subscribed to value changes. The value should be definitely correct, no weird race conditions. The thing is that even with your suggested solution to debug it the color does not change.

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz with out code?